# How to fix TypeError: cy.document(...).toMatchSnapshot is not a function?

Tags: angular, angular7, e2e-testing, cypress

I am trying to do snapshot testing for my e2e test on my page by using Cypress and [cypress-plugin-snapshots](https://github.com/meinaart/cypress-plugin-snapshots).

But I got this error `TypeError: cy.document(...).toMatchSnapshot is not a function`.

Here are my configurations:

plugins/index.js

```
const { initPlugin } = require('cypress-plugin-snapshots/plugin');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
  initPlugin(on, config);
  return config;
}
```

support/index.js

```
import 'cypress-plugin-snapshots/src/commands';
```

cypress.json

```
{
    "ignoreTestFiles": [
        "**/__snapshots__/*",
        "**/__image_snapshots__/*"
    ]
}
```

home.spec.js

```
context('Querying', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.server();
        cy.fixture('user.json').as('userJSON');
        cy.route('GET', 'users?id=*', '@userJSON').as('getUser');
        cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/1');
    })

    it.only('LANDING - Snapshot test', () => {
        cy.wait(['@getUser']);
        cy.document().toMatchSnapshot()
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue. Your code should be:

```
expect(cy.document()).toMatchSnapshot()
```

Note the `expect`

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong import. It should be:

```
import 'cypress-plugin-snapshots/commands';
```

instead of

```
import 'cypress-plugin-snapshots/src/commands';
```